# Can I couple 1064 nm and its harmonic 532 nm in a single polarization maintaining fiber?

Tags: optics, laser, polarization, fiber-optics, waveguide

I have an experiment where I need to get a largish (40 mW) amount of 532 nm light and small amount (<50 µW) of 1064 nm light into a device under test. I need something with stable polarization so would like to use polarization maintaining fiber.  I know that single mode fibers have some cut off at V<2.405 so there will be some issues with some loss to higher order modes for the shorter wavelength, but I can live with loss at 532 nm.

I'm wondering if I can use a PM fiber designed for 1064 nm (say thorlabs PM980-XP [1](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PM980-XP)) and launch both 1064 nm and 532 nm co-propagating light? I'd like to be able to estimate the mode-field-diameter (for losses at the device interface) and and maybe the V-number of both wavelengths but the fiber manufacture doesn't give all the details about fiber refractive index.  I'm also not sure if these panda style fibers have a different calculation for figuring out most of these characteristic numbers.

Will panda style PM fibers be polarization maintaining so far outside their design wavelength?

I know it seems like a very specific question but there are probably a bunch of people in labs wondering the same thing.

Comment: I have to think about this a bit, but I suspect that the 9-um PM fiber will not be effective at maintaining polarization at 532 nm. On the other hand, if the fiber is not too long and not too tightly bent, coupling between two polarization modes will not be very strong anyway.

Comment: This is a probably going to be a 1 or 2 meter long patch cable.  Maybe there is no need to use PM at all?

Comment: @awade even if the fibre does not maintain the polarisation at 532nm as long as the fibre isn't terribly long and the temperature doesn't change much it will just give a fixed unitary rotation of the polarisation state (if it is long the fibre may depolarise the light a little and if the temperature or orientation of the fibre change it time the unitary will be time varying) and so you can recover the polarisation you need with some wave plates before the fibre.